# How can i automate selecting colors from color chrome- picker webElement

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, color-picker

Hi I am new to selenium and I am learning automation through online courses. Recently I came across a situation where I need to automate the color picking from a pop up. And I am struggling to find the answer. I need to select a color from color chrome-picker pop up  WebElement.  I can either select color from the box or I can drag the slider to choose color. I want to do both. Please suggest some code to automate this. I tried using javascript executor. But it is not clicking/dragging and strangely it is not showing as failed when I execute my tests. Thank you.

This is the chrome-picker class webElement:

[image: This is the chrome-picker class webElement]

and

[image: html tag]

I tried the following code to drag the icons and slider in the image.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
         WebElement ColorElement =subChrome1.findElement(
                  By.cssSelector("div[style="position: absolute; inset: 0px; background: rgb(0, 164, 255");]"));
         Actions slide=new Actions(driver);
         slide.dragAndDropBy(ColorElement, -300, i).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a Windows color picker popup, and you can use AutoIT or the JavaScript code below, which may be useful.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("chrome-picker "));
JavascriptExecutor javascriptexecutor=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
javascriptexecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','#FFEEXX')",element);
```